# Why I got: Requires installation of untrusted packages

Tags: package-management, update-manager, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updates don't install because of “untrusted packages”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15655/updates-dont-install-because-of-untrusted-packages)

I got

"Requires installation of untrusted packages
The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources."

with list of packages:
"gir1.2-panelapplet-3.0 gnome-panel gnome-panel-bonobo gnome-panel-data libpanel-applet-3-0 libpanel-applet2-0 libplymouth2 libpulse-browse0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text postfix pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python-glade2 python-gtk2 software-center ubuntu-docs ubuntu-sso-client update-manager update-manager-core"

I udestand why this happen literally - but I do not know why I have untrusted packages in my Ubuntu.

In my understanding there are two ot three possibilities:

1. I installed untrasted packages to my ubuntu -but in that case I shuld add certificake to my repo and then I should not receive this king od message
2. I suspect Janitor removed some certificates and this is a cause
3. something else.

Please help,
T