# I can't download from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't install software from the software center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77487/i-cant-install-software-from-the-software-center)

After I press install it says:

> Please check your internet connection

After I click ok, it says:

> Require installation of untrusted packages , The action would required
>   the installation of packages from not authenticated source

Comment: Whenever this happens to me, I install them through synaptic or the terminal and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the problem ("require installation of untrusted packages...") looks like a duplicate of
[Updates don't install because of "untrusted packages"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15655/updates-dont-install-because-of-untrusted-packages)